# Как сделать bat файл запускаемым с любого места файловой системы

Tags: cmd, bat

У меня есть лабораторная работа на тему подготовки .bat файла, которая выглядит так

1. Перейти на директорию выше относительно директории, в которой находится bat-файл и создать
   там директорию с именем ‘Practice0’.
2. Создать в директории ‘Practice0’ поддиректорию ‘Test’ и в ней создать файл ‘about.me’, в котором
   в первой строке записать своё имя и фамилию, а во второй – название университета, который
   закончили или в котором учитесь.
3. Переместить файл ‘about.me’ в директорию ‘Practice0’ и присвоить ему атрибут ‘read only’.
4. Вывести информацию из файла ’about.me’ в виде: [Ваша имя и фамилия] учусь/учился в
   [название университета].

В отчете же сказано что

2. Сделайте созданный bat-файл запускаемым с любого места файловой системы.

Вот пример моего кода в .bat файле

```
cd ..
md Practice0
cd Practice0
md Test
cd Test
NUL> about.me.txt
echo Name Surname >> about.me.txt
echo University >> about.me.txt
MOVE A:\lab1\Practice0\Test\about.me.txt A:\lab1\Practice0
pause
```

Вопрос заключается в 3 пункте, как сделать так, чтобы файл запускался из любого места, ведь при переносе файла я указываю полный путь до него, и если я перенесу батник куда-то в другое место, он выдает ошибку

Comment: А что, "move about.me.txt ../about.me.txt" не срабатывает?

Comment: сработало, спасибо большое

Comment: Пожалуйста. В качестве бонуса можно ещё попробовать комбинацию: сначала "cd ..", а потом "copy Test/about.me.txt ." - тоже должно сработать. Ну и в уже отработанном примере второй раз имя файла, насколько я помню, можно не указывать: достаточно "move about.me.txt ../" - вроде тоже может сработать. Так, для общего представления может быть полезно)

Comment: по заданию еще "присвоить ему атрибут ‘read only’." добавьте attrib +r about.me.txt

Comment: Если решение подошло - отметьте его как ответ, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сработало :)

```
move about.me.txt ../about.me.txt
```

Учитывая, что мы находимся в каталоге Test, мы можем скопировать файл "about.me.txt" в каталог уровнем выше, используя префикс "../", который и ссылается на родительский каталог.

Comment: *Учитывая, что мы находимся в каталоге Test* С какой радости? Батч может быть запущен при любом текущем диске и каталоге.

Comment: Эээээм, ну с такой радости, что каталог *Test* мы создаём сами и сами в него переходим с помощью команды cd. При этом изначально мы можем находиться хоть на рабочем столе (и тогда получится структура "~/desktop/practice0/test/about.me.txt", хоть в корне диска d, и тогда у нас получится структура "d:/practice 0/test/about.me.txt". Можете привести пример, в котором между командами "cd test" и "move ..." у нас ВНЕЗАПНО и неожиданно для нас сменится рабочая директория?

Comment: Почитал Ваш ответ и, кажется, понял, что Вы имеете в виду - речь не о том, что мы находимся в каталоге Test, а о том, что сам каталог может быть создан не в том родительском каталоге, если изначально текущая/рабочая директория не совпадает с той, в которой лежит бат-файл. Замечание совершенно справедливое, но изначальный вопрос автора всё же был скорее про захардкоженные пути, ИМХО)

Answer (score 1):

```sh
@echo off

# перейти на диск, где находится батч-файл, в каталог "на этаж выше"
cd /d "%~dp0.."

# остальные команды
```

Если в батче надо получить диск/путь к батчу - соответственно используйте `"%~dp0"` (использовать в команде либо присвоить в переменную среды). Более подробно по выделению компонентов см. `for /?`. В батче `%0` - это нулевой параметр комстроки, т.е. полное имя самого батча.